# PCRE2 Regex error escape sequence is invalid in character class

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex expression, for whatever reason I keep getting an error when using this with PCRE2. I'm unsure what would be causing the error.

```
/^.(?=.{1,})(?=.[A-Z])(?=.[0-9])(?=.[\d\X])(?=(?:.[!@#$%^&()\\\-_=\+{}[\]|;:,.]){1,}).{8,}$/
```

The error in the log is:

exception: preg_match(): Compilation failed: escape sequence is invalid in character class at offset 43

Comment: The problem is `\X`, but I'm not sure how to fix it. It looks like it works in certain versions of PCRE. Just adding `u` modifier doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this [Red Hat Bugzilla bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1706742), this is a [documented PCRE2 behavior](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html):

> **Escape sequences in character classes**
> All the sequences that define a
> single character value can be used both inside and outside character
> classes. In addition, inside a character class, `\b` is interpreted as
> the backspace character (hex 08).
>
> When not followed by an opening brace, `\N` is not allowed in a
> character class. `\B`, `\R`, and `\X` are not special inside a character
> class. Like other unrecognized alphabetic escape sequences, they cause
> an error. Outside a character class, these sequences have different
> meanings.

To fix your regex, I'd suggest something like

```
if (preg_match('/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&()\\\\_=+{}[\]|;:,.-]).{8,}$/', 'aB9!ssssddssdd')){
    echo "yes";
}
```

where

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - at least one uppercase ASCII letter
- `(?=.*[a-z])`  - at least one lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?=.*[0-9])`  - at least one ASCII digit
- `(?=.*[!@#$%^&()\\\\_=+{}[\]|;:,.-])` - at least one special char, `!`, `@`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `^`, `&`, `(`, `)`, `\`, `_`, `=`, `+`, `{`, `}`, `[`, `]`, `|`, `;`, `:`, `,`, `.` and `-`
- `.{8,}` - at least 8 chars, no line breaks
- `$` - end  of string.