# preg_match(): Compilation failed php upgrade from 5.6 to 7.4

Tags: php, laravel

I have this password field on admin

[image]

But after upgrading php I got this error

`preg_match(): Compilation failed: escape sequence is invalid in character class at offset 46`

I have this validator pattern

```
 $rules = [
            'firstname' => 'required|max:255',
            'lastname' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:tblClient,fldClientEmail',
            'password' => 'required|min:8|regex:/^.*(?=.{1,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X]).*$/'
        ];
```

is there changes needs to apply on my regex?

Note: original setup
Laravel Framework version 5.1.46 (LTS)
PHP 5.6

But Project Manager asks me to upgrade to PHP 7.4

Current setup as of now is
Laravel Framework version 5.1.46 (LTS)
php7.4

Comment: Did you upgrade Laravel to a compatible version of PHP 7?

Comment: Just the php, Im using Laravel Framework version 5.1.46 (LTS) & upgraded to php 7.4

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Current setup is Laravel Framework version 5.1.46 (LTS)  and php 7.4

Comment: Laravel 5.5 or newer is recommended for PHP 7
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PCRE2 Regex error escape sequence is invalid in character class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64248370/pcre2-regex-error-escape-sequence-is-invalid-in-character-class)

Comment: To summarize: you need to remove the `\X` in the regex.

Comment: Follow @HPierce advice. As a side note: you should also update also the version of Laravel. It will save you a ton of headaches. You could use Laravel Shift to automate that.

Comment: For anyone who is not familiary with `\X` -- it matches (a single unicode grapheme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55783469/2943403)

Comment: `{1,}` can be reduced to `+`. If your pattern does not require case-sensitivity, use the `i` pattern modifier to avoid `[a-zA-Z]`.  The first lookahead is redundant anyhow, because the other lookaheads require at least one character anyhow.  `[0-9]` can be reduced to `\d`.  I don't know what that last lookahead is trying to do, but maybe you mean to require a non-alphanumeric character?  Probably better to try a negated character class for that.  I don't know that those `.*` matches or the start/end anchors are necessary at all.  (Note: I don't Laravel)